# change text to input and back to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, blur

I have a product list, price is normal text. When I click in  with price, I want to replace text by input and when I call the blur event, it update DB data and replace input by text.

I have this code:

```
<td>
    <span onclick="make_field(this, 'text', '11', '12,350.00')">12,350.00</span> €
</td>
<script>
    function make_field(el, type, id, val) {
        var el = $(el);

        el.html('<input onblur="update_db_row(params); make_el(this, \'span\', ' + id + ', \'' + val + '\', \'' + **this.value** + '\')" type=' + type + ' name=' + id + ' value="' + val.replace(',',' ').replace(',',' ').replace('.',',') + '">'); // replace 12,350.00 to 12350,00
        el.attr('onclick', '');
    }

    function make_el(el, tag_name, id, old_value, **new_value**) {
        var el = $(el);

        alert(old_value);
        alert(new_value); // undefined, how I can give current input value to function when I click outside the input?
  }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can achieve that using [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) library, is pretty easy to use and well documented.

Comment: Emilio, thanks for comment... I want to avoid using library if I want only one function. It should be only this one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QLkJB/)

You can obtain the new value directly from the input element, as follows:

```
 function make_field(el, type, id, val) {

    var el = $(el);

    el.html('<input onblur="update_db_row(); make_el(this, \'span\', ' + id + ', \'' + val + '\')" type=' + type + ' name=' + id + ' value="' + val.replace(',', ' ').replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ',') + '">'); // replace 12,350.00 to 12350,00
    el.attr('onclick', '');


}


function make_el(el, tag_name, id, old_value) {
    var el = $(el);

    // Get the new value directly from the input.
    var new_value = el.val();

    // Set the new value on the span and remove the input box.
    el.parent().html(new_value);
    el.remove();
}

function update_db_row() {}
```

Comment: Greg: Yes, it´s exactly what I need. Thanks.